# How to support multiple locale buffer with UBreakIterator

Tags: locale, icu

How can I use UBreakIterator with a buffer having different locale?
eg: 金魚 わたしワタシ മലബാറിൽ കെട്ടിയാടപ്പെടുന്ന महाभारत हिन्दुओं का स्मृति
वर्ग में, is having multiple locale strings. How can I use
UBreakIterator so that it will break on every word by considering its
locale?

I tried this with "ja_JP" in a C program and it is working as
expected, but not with "en_US". What should be the correct locale
value to ubrk_open so that this will work for every language?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Manoj Marathayil

Answer (score 0):

You might break the string apart by script (uchar.h) and then run a break over each script run.